# Display value as returned from controller method

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning, aura-framework

Beginner in Salesforce so please bear with me.
I have created a lightning component and I would like to display on a page a value as returned by a component controller.

```
public class My_Controller { 
@AuraEnabled
public static Decimal getRate(String currFrom, String currTo) {

Decimal value = 1.067773;

return value;  
}
}

<aura:component controller="My_Controller">

<lightning:input type="string" name="res" aura:id="res" value= " 
{!c.My_Controller.getRate('A', 'B')}" label="Result"/>
```

But it could not be so simple :) as I get: "Failed to save Rate.cmp: unexpected token: '(' at column 46 of expression: c.My_Controller.getRate('A', 'B'): Source"

What is the proper way to call the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call an Apex server controller method directly from Lightning clientside markup.

Instead, you'd need to declare an [`<aura:attribute>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_aura_attribute.htm) in your component markup and bind the value to that attribute.

```
<aura:attribute name="rate" type="String" />
<lightning:input type="string" name="res" aura:id="res" value="{! v.rate }" label="Result"/>
```

Then, your JavaScript client-side controller needs to make a [server-side call](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm), asynchronously, to get the value from Apex. Finally, the Lightning JavaScript callback from that async method would populate the return value into the `<aura:attribute>`, and the framework's data binding infrastructure will take care of updating the `<lightning:input>`.

It sounds complex, but it's mostly boilerplate code. The documentation linked above includes detailed examples.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class My_Controller { 
@AuraEnabled
public static Decimal getRate(String currFrom, String currTo) {

Decimal value = 1.067773;

return value;  
}
}

<aura:component controller="My_Controller">
<aura:attribute name = "value" type= "Decimal"/>
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<lightning:input type="string" name="res" aura:id="res" value= " 
{!v.value}" label="Result"/>

<aura:component>

add a new method in controller.js:-
({

    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getRate");
        action.setParams({
            "currFrom": 'Test',
            "currTo"  : 'Test'
        });

        action.setCallback( this, function(actionResult) {
            var state = actionResult.getState();
            component.set('v.spinner',false);
            if (state === "SUCCESS"){
                var result = actionResult.getReturnValue();
                component.set("v.value",result);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
    })
```